# Time Capsule partly stops working after some hours

Tags: macos, backup, macbook-pro, time-capsule, airport

I have a new TimeCapsule 2TB and use it as a wireless AP, router, and backup device. The TimeCapsule is directly connected to the DSL modem.

When I turn on the TimeCapsule, everything works fine. But after some hours (maybe 2-4), my MacBook Air no longer finds the TimeCapsule, so backups via TimeMachine fail.  Also, AirPort utility no longer finds the TimeCapsule. The strange thing is: the wireless internet connection on my MacBook Air is still perfectly working and I'm also able to mount the TimeCapsule's disk from a Linux machine via Samba. After switching the TimeCapsule off and on again, the AirPort utility finds the TimeCapsule without problems.

Any ideas how to solve or debug this problem? I'm using Mac OS Lion, AirPort utility 5.5.3 and firmware version 7.5.2 of the TimeCapsule.

Comment: Does it happen after your Mac has woken from sleep, maybe? What version of Lion are you using (Apple » About this Mac)?

Answer (score 1):

Try restoring to default settings. This won't erase any data stored on the Time Capsule, it will reset the network configuration.

Open AirPort Utility (***Applications > Utilities > AirPort Utility***) and right click on your time capsule. Select ***Restore Default Settings...***

[image: AirPort Utility Restore Defaults]

Then wait for it to restart, and follow the setup instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, the temporary fix seems to be to turn wireless off and on again on your Mac.

I'm still searching for a more permanent fix.